# How to fix "Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)"

Tags: python, django, api, csrf

When I send some data from my front-end via axios, my API give error Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

I use csrf_exempt to avoid this error, however it doesn't help me

**views.py:**

```py
@csrf_exempt
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        if not is_user_data_valid_for_create(data):
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
        user_role = Role.objects.get(pk=1)
        user = User.create(
            first_name=data['first_name'],
            last_name=data['last_name'],
            email=data['email'],
            password=data['password'],
            role=user_role
        )
        return HttpResponse("Success,{} your account created!".format(user.first_name), status=201)
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

**This is my code on React:**

```html
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            first_name: '',
            last_name: '',
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }

    changeHandler = event => {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    };

    submitHandler = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state);
        axios
            .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/restration/', this.state)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    };

<form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <div className="user-data">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="John" name="first_name" value={first_name}
                               onChange={this.changeHandler} className="form-control"/>
                            </div>
...
                  <div className="sign-up-w">
                      <button type="submit" className="btn-primary sing-up">SIGN UP</button>
                  </div>
</form>
```

When I send data from UI I have the error:

> Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/v1/user/restration/
>
> "POST /api/v1/user/restration/ HTTP/1.1" 403
> 2868

However, when I send data via Postman everything is okay.

Answer (score 1):

If you have CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE to be True in your settings file, then the cookie will be marked as "secure" and will need an HTTPS connection.

Which is why you receive that error.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure

Comment: No, I didn't set a CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE in settings

Comment: Try, setting CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE as false, explicityly in  your settings.py

Comment: It didn't help, as I know django by default set False for CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE

Comment: Are you using django rest framework or just django?

Comment: Just django, is it important?

Comment: I have the same problem also, Mine when listening to stripe webhook from the cli interface on the console for stripe I could see the events were called but on console to local host I get this error `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)` django 3.1